# Denied Select Permission to Table in Stored Procedure - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

I created a user `testUser` and assigned it to newly created role `executive`.

I then created the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.spTest
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT FirstName, LastName 
    FROM dbo.Emp
END
```

And granted the permission to execute that stored procedure to role:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.spTest TO executive
```

When I try executing the stored procedure using the `testUser`, I get the following error message:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Emp', database , schema 'dbo'

Everything I read online says that the `GRANT EXECUTE` line should work, but it clearly doesn't. I've also read that this error message appears if for dynamic SQL, but I'm pretty sure this is static.

I don't know why it doesn't work. Can anyone help?

**edit**: I don't want to give SELECT permission to the Emp table (has sensitive data).

Comment: Make sure the user `executive` has `SELECT` permission on that table...

Comment: Are you SP and table in the same DB?

Comment: @AaronDietz:  I thought execute permission is enough, even though user may not have read permission to underlying table: [see here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54926/rights-to-execute-stored-procedure-but-not-read-underlying-tables-directly)

Comment: Is the role `executive` actually assigned to `testUser`?

Comment: @Hooman Hmm I guess `execute` is enough, thanks for the info

Comment: Looks like this can also happen [when ownership chains are wrong](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24555/select-permission-inside-stored-procedure)

Comment: @Crowcoder I tried changing the ownership but didn't work

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, I am using Azure SQL Data Warehouse. Does this matter?

Comment: Can you add a script to your question that fully reproduces the error?   (creates the user, role, table, does the assignments, etc...)